# Find "primary key" for any pyspark dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I find the combination of columns in a data set (pyspark) that can be considered the primary key.

I tried to generate the combination of all the columns then compare the number of distinct records of each subset with the whole set, but it is very expensive.

```
from itertools import combinations

l_key = []

for i in range(len(df.columns)+1):
  print(f'Iter:{i+2}..{len(df.columns)+1}')
  for c in list(combinations(df.columns, i+2)):
    if(df.select(*c).distinct().count() == df.count()):
      l_key.append(c)
      print(f'Key:{c}')
```

Are there any functions or libraries that can generate this type of analysis?

Comment: does it have to be a combination of existing columns? or it could be generated key?

Comment: For Databricks environments, the `information_schema` tables provide primary key info for tables managed via _Unity Catalog_:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150620/764307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it by creating the combinations as columns and then grouping.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

pdf = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1]], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

initCols = df.columns

for i in range(len(initCols)+1):
    for c in list(combinations(initCols, i+2)):
        df = df.withColumn(','.join(c), F.concat_ws(',', *c))

finalCols = df.columns

exprs = [F.size(F.collect_set(x)).alias(x) for x in finalCols]

df = df\
.withColumn("aggCol", F.lit("a"))\
.groupBy("aggCol")\
.agg(*exprs)

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
|aggCol|  x|  y|  z|x,y|x,z|y,z|x,y,z|
+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
|     a|  3|  2|  1|  3|  3|  2|    3|
+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

I believe this should be less expensive. I tested it quickly on a small dataframe (~20k rows, 7 cols) and it didn't take too much time. Let me know how this works out for your dataset.