# How to identify the primary key of a table in databricks using SparkSql or Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I tried using this as my code but was not able to get the output!
SHOW PRIMARY KEYS
[ IN { ACCOUNT | DATABASE [ <database_name> ] | SCHEMA [ <schema_name> ] | TABLE | [ TABLE ] <table_name> } ]

Answer (score 1):

In Databricks, as long as you are using the *Unity Catalog*, you can query the information schema to obtain the primary keys of a table via:

```sql
system.information_schema.key_column_usage.column_name
```

I've found a number of errors in their documentation on this, but I can confirm that this query works successfully for me on the latest versions of Databricks:

```sql
SELECT
  cu.constraint_catalog,
  cu.constraint_schema,
  cu.constraint_name,
  cu.table_catalog,
  cu.table_schema,
  cu.table_name,
  cu.column_name,
  cu.ordinal_position,
  cu.position_in_unique_constraint
FROM system.information_schema.key_column_usage AS cu
JOIN system.information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
  USING (constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name)
WHERE cu.table_name = '<<TABLE-NAME>>'
  AND tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, Spark doesn't have built-in concept of the primary key that will be enforcing uniqueness. There is a concept of the partition key (you can use [SHOW PARTITIONS](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-partitions.html)), but it's a different thing used to separate data files by some specific key